# Flutter How to share File image via share plug in

Tags: flutter, share, file-sharing

```
Hello and thank you in advance!
```

I am working on image editing. I can pick the image from the image picker and rewrite it with the help of drawstringdrawstring. I can save the image in my documentDirectory. I want to share my image from documentDirectory path via the Share plugin. However, I am getting an error.

The code and error details are as shown below.

Code:

```
  FlatButton(
  child: Text("Apply Watermark Over Image"),
  onPressed: () async {
    final image1 = ui.decodeImage(_originalImage.readAsBytesSync());

    ui.drawString(image1, ui.arial_24, 300, 400, 'Hello And thank you');


    final documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    final file = new File(p.join(documentDirectory.path, "merged_image.jpg"));
   
    file.writeAsBytesSync(ui.encodeJpg(image1));
      // I HAVE THE IMAGE IN - documentDirectory.path "HERE I CANT SHARE THAT IMAGE" 
    final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load(documentDirectory.path);
    await Share.file('esys image', 'esys.png', bytes.buffer.asUint8List(), 'image/png', 
    text: 'My optional text.');
  },
)
```

I am getting this error :

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: /data/user/0/com.photogranth.watermark/app_flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For share file image you can use this [share_files_and_screenshot_widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/share_files_and_screenshot_widgets)

```
  FlatButton(
  onPressed: () async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

      File f = File('${directory.path}/mycsv.csv');

      String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(data);

      await f.writeAsString(csv);

      var file_as_bytes = await f.readAsBytes();

      Uint8List list = file_as_bytes.buffer.asUint8List();

      ShareFilesAndScreenshotWidgets().shareFile(
          "Title", "Name.csv", list, "text/csv",
          text: "This is the caption!");
              },
)
```

Comment: Your welcome, if this answer is true for your please vote to helpful for other user

Comment: ofcurse..! Now one error is come when image is share ::: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://com.photogranth.watermark.contentprovider/images/image.png from pid=6574, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()

Comment: Do u know why this came

Comment: Yes, you must to add Permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: this package shows it's been discontinued